# Apacheds Unlock Account

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds

I am using Apacheds server for authentication. Account gets locked after some incorrect bind attempts.

I can unlock the account using Apache Directory Studio by just deleting pwdAccountLockedTime but is there a way to unlock account from java code using Apache LDAP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do the same using code. (You should bind as administrator to perform this).

Comment: Yes, that much I understand and did, but do I have to delete pwdAccountLockedTime, is there no other way???

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want this behavior then you could modify the password policies. Set a value in ds-pwdLockoutDuration which is

> The delay in seconds we wait before allowing a new attempt when the
>   password has been locked

You can look here: [How to unlock user on ApacheDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348831/how-to-unlock-user-on-apacheds)

And here : https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem, using above method only. Secondly, at that time, I wanted to unlock manually, and was finding an elegant method. But I think your solution will be helpful if I wanted to unlock automatically after, some period of time.