# How to unlock user on ApacheDS

Tags: ldap, apacheds, password-policy

I setup an ApacheDS with default password-policy enabled. For testing proposes I locked a simple User (objectClass=Person extended with some custom User-objectClass) by entering the wrong credentials a number of times. As I expected the user was locked (error msg: user was permanently locked).

The question now is: How to unlock the user again? Is there a better way then just deleting and adding again?

I tried the same with an extended user (objectClass=pwdPolicy) but no pwd* attributes were added when the user was locked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More recently, I encountered the same problem at work. But, it seems that there is no answer on Internet. Finally,I found the answer by viewing this document:

[Password Policy for LDAP Directories draft-behera-ldap-password-policy](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10)

- At section 5.3.3: pwdAccountLockedTime

> This attribute holds the time that the user's account was locked.  A
> locked account means that the password may no longer be used to
> authenticate.  A 000001010000Z value means that the account has been
> locked permanently, and that ***only a password administrator can unlock
> the account***.

- At section 5.2.12: pwdLockoutDuration

> This attribute holds the number of seconds that the password cannot
> be used to authenticate due to too many failed bind attempts.  If
> this attribute is not present, or ***if the value is 0 the password
>
> cannot be used to authenticate until reset by a password
>
> administrator***.

Through above two section, we can assume that we should connect to ApacheDS server with administrator(by default: uid=admin,ou=system, password=secret ), and delete the user's userPassword attribute. By this way,the permanently locked user can be unlock.

I practiced this sulotion and it works well.

I suggest you should set value for **pwdLockoutDuration** attribute, in this case the user can not been permanently locked.

For more infomation:

[ApacheDS password Policy](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that. Locking the account for several minutes/hours should be enough to block brute force attack. Otherwise the user can reset the password (deleting the old one and creating a new one).

Comment: You are right, user can reset their password. But when user under permanently locked, it can not unlock the use by reset their password with non-administrator privileges. Only through administrator.

Comment: Log in as admin, find the user, right-clik and choose "Fetch->Fetch operational attributes". Now pwdAccountLockedTime is visible and you can delete it to unlocks the user.

Answer (score 8):

Use [ApacheDS Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) and log in as admin, find the user, right-click and choose "Fetch->Fetch operational attributes". Now pwdAccountLockedTime is visible and you can delete it to unlocks the user

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Mister's is perfect to unlock an account and if you want to set the `pwdLockoutDuration` for a single user (assuming the user has implemnted the objectClass `pwdPolicy`.

There is also a global config file found in:

```
ou=config
  *  ads-directoryServiceId=<default>
    * ou=interceptors
       * ads-interceptorId=authenticationInterceptor
          * ou=passwordPolicies
```

Here we can set the default password policy:

[image]

As mine is just a test-server, I have completely disabled lockout via setting the `ads-pwdlockout` to `FALSE`. For more on configuring password policy read the [official docs](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is how you enable this on the server via java:

```
AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor = new AuthenticationInterceptor();      
PasswordPolicyConfiguration config = new PasswordPolicyConfiguration();
config.setPwdLockout(true);
authenticationInterceptor.setPwdPolicies(config);
```

Client methods can then be written, to enable/disable specific accounts, similar to:

```
 public void disableUser(String dn) throws LdapException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
 {
   Modification disablePassword = new DefaultModification( 
   ModificationOperation.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, "pwdAccountLockedTime","000001010000Z" );
   connection.modify(dn,disablePassword);
 }   

 public void enableUser(String dn) throws LdapException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
 {    
   Modification disablePassword = new DefaultModification(ModificationOperation.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, "pwdAccountLockedTime");
   connection.modify(dn,disablePassword);
 }
```